# Where can I purchase all the children's gift items?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I have just finished my base house in Hearthfire. I adopted two children. They are all nice, I can play tag with them and all. I have an option to give them gifts.

Where can I buy all the gifts? Out of my inventory I can gift them the Dagger, but rather not gift them that, they might hurt themselves.

Wikia says wooden sword, child's doll, children's clothing etc as potential gifts.

I tried Bits n Pieces in Solitude and Radiant Raiments in Solitude for the children's clothing. But they did not have it.

Where can I buy them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can purchase those gifts from general merchants (Bits n Pieces in Solitude, Lucan Valerius in Riverwood, Gray Pine Goods in Falkreath, etc), under the "misc" section.

Note that children's clothing will appear also under "misc", not as "apparel".

Answer (score 3):

Radiant Raiments has the best child apparel and the hidden chest in Dawnstar has a wooden sword for the boy and a doll for the girl.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the hidden chest in dawnstar. I always get some form of child item in there
or you can just steal the items off of someone else.

They wont hurt themselves if given a dagger.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an ingame spouse, then you can buy stuff from his/her store.