# What items can you give your children?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Which items can I give to my children as a gift?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/103616/where-can-i-purchase-all-the-childrens-gift-items?

Answer (score 6):

You can give them these things:

- Sweet treats like taffy, sweet rolls, and apples
- Any kind of daggers, which include wooden swords
- Clothes for children (dresses or shirts, depending on the
  sex of the child), which will appear under Miscellaneous in your inventory
- Dolls, which will also appear under Misc.

You can also give them coins when they ask you for money.

Comment: Apples!  They're all over the friggin' place, so I always carry one.  Also, among weapons, you can only give daggers to your child, among which is the "Wooden Sword".

Comment: I just give them 1000 gold every time.  I have about half a million and nothing to spend it on.

Comment: It should be noted that wooden swords can also be enchanted (and given to your children)

Answer (score -2):

I gave her a dagger once. It was a named dagger but there are a few of them out there. Named like "death blade" or "blade of the dead". I can't remember what it was actually called but it was killing related. I got it from a cult like member.

Comment: This is just one example. The question is looking for a more complete list of items.

Answer (score -3):

I was able to give my girl a book of riddles. Pretty neat.

Comment: This is just one example. The question is looking for a more complete list of items.